# Delete mysql and join in where

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete

The below query in my sql throws "You can't specify target table 'd' for update in FROM clause"

```
DELETE FROM d 
using mdm_certificate_data as d  
where d.trash = 1 and d.modified_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
AND NOT EXISTS 
    (select e.serial_number as serial_number 
        FROM mdm_certificate_data e 
        WHERE e.serial_number = d.serial_number 
        and e.serial_number IN ('12345','1234567'));
```

Can some one help me rewrite the query?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing an `UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE` on a table, you can't reference that table in an inner query (you can, however, reference a field from that outer table...)

One way of rewriting this is,

```
DELETE FROM d 
using mdm_certificate_data as d  
where d.trash = 1 and d.modified_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
AND NOT EXISTS 
    (select temp.serial_number as serial_number 
        FROM (select e.serial_number from mdm_certificate_data) temp
            WHERE temp.serial_number = d.serial_number 
            and temp.serial_number IN ('12345','1234567'));
```